# OL3 error with Style function

Tags: geojson, style, openlayers

I am trying to style a .json layer with a numbe of classes based on an attribute.

I and getting the error below which is apparently in ol3.js based on debugging in chrome:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'e' of undefined
```

I have tried to use ol-debug but then I get errors earlier on

The code I am using for the layer is

```
var lyr_RoFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({url: 'layers/RoFS.geojson'}), 
      title: "Risk of Flooding",
      style: (function() {
          var defaultStyle = [new ol.style.Style({
             fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'navy'}),
             stroke: new ol.style.Stroke( {color: 'black', width: 1})
             })];
          var ruleStyle = [new ol.style.Style({
             fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'olive'}),
             stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'black', width: 1})
             })];
          return function(feature, resolution) {
              if (feature.get('prob_4band') === 'High') {
                 return ruleStyle;
              } else {
                 return defaultStyle;
              }
          };
      })
```

Comment: What's the error if you use `ol-debug.js` instead of `ol.js`?

Comment: Hi. I have edited your code layout, and I can see that you are missing ')}' . Is the code you have written complete or did you forget something?